# Can age affect how carbohydrates affects your energy level?

Tags: nutrition, energy, carbohydrates

I've read that eating a lot of products containing  carbohydrates can make you feel tired. However, when I was younger (pre-20) I never noticed this effect. Currently 25 and noticed being tires quite soon after eating a larger portion of carbohydrates. Can this Change be due to age or could it be other lifestyle changes?

---

I may have some terms mixed up, but basically lately feeling tired after eating which didn't occur about a few years ago. I have, however, stepped into a bit more healthy lifestyle, eating less and actually training once / twice a week.

Comment: At 80 , everything you neat makes you feel tired.